# How memory will be deleted?

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory

Let's say I have structure

```
struct Foo {
    int whatever;
    int whatever2;
    ...
};
```

And I have this type of array

```
Foo **array = new Foo*[128];
```

Then, to every pointer I assign new structure

```
for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
    array[i] = new Foo;
```

Then, after a while I deallocate:

```
delete[] array;
```

How memory will be deallocated?

1. Only the space for pointers will be freed
2. Space for pointer + the objects pointed by those pointers themselves?

Comment: It's #1. Just use `std::vector<Foo>`.

Comment: For every `new []`, you need a `delete []`. For every `new`, you need a `delete`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code leaks memory. You need to call `delete` once for every `new` call (assuming the `new` doesn't fail and either return `NULL` or throw `bad_alloc`). So, in this case, you'll need to have a similar loop to the one that calls `array[i] = new Foo;` that does `delete array[i];`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one of points in Scott Meyers book, Effective C++ have read long back. But basic idea is, to avoid memory leak when you use new. make sure to call delete as many times as new is called and map new with delete and new[] with delete[] accordingly. so in your case new is called 128 times in for loop and new[] is called once, so similarly delete should be called same way to array[i] 128 times and delete[] should be called once for array. Hope this helps.